# Book Shelf: Rigid Body Sim- Books thrown out

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm working on a bookshelf animation, nothing fancy just the books falling into place.
I applied rigid body properties to both the book (active) and the shelf (passive). Upon playing the simulation, the book appears to be thrown away from the shelf rather than falling into place.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blender's rigid body simulator isn't perfect. you can change sensitivity (under collissions) to make it more accurate and change shape (also under collissions) to mesh

Comment: I tried doing that but the simulation seems not right. Sensitivity and shape of the books?